# android crash report (cordova/crosswalk)

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Hi I'm gettings this crash report from store. It's not for all devices, but for some (rare). Does any one know what the problem is from this?

My app is built with Cordova/Crosswalk android app.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/ms013gxx/ms013g:4.4.2/KOT49H/G7102XWUBNK1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '7'
pid: 2574, tid: 2604, name: WorkerPool/2604 >>> com.myapp.id <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 73d4b2e0
r0 7c3ee878 r1 402862e8 r2 fffff320 r3 4024a679
r4 73d8b330 r5 7c3ee878 r6 402862e8 r7 40136394
r8 00000000 r9 7baadb78 sl 00000001 fp 00000000
ip 00000000 sp 73d4b2e8 lr 405945ff pc 4024a678 cpsr 00070030
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 4020000000000000 d5 bebbb63036c79c05
d6 0000014072bea4d0 d7 43a0000000000140
d8 000000003f800000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0414181e06014d51 d17 000002ba1a000018
d18 003a0074006e0069 d19 006e006100220020
d20 0069006f00720064 d21 00720064003a0064
d22 0062006100770061 d23 006f002f0065006c
d24 3f95c966ebf3f9e8 d25 bf95c966c155d531
d26 402213664f3f26db d27 4000000000000000
d28 3ffcea4783f8a3fe d29 bfcc400000000026
d30 3ff0000000000000 d31 40c3880000000005
scr 60000010

backtrace:
#00 pc 00088678 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (register_android_graphics_Typeface(_JNIEnv*)+23)
#01 pc 03000004 <unknown>

code around pc:
4024a658 0003cc8e ffffff68 23064903 44794a03 
4024a668 f7cd447a bf00b825 0002e0d5 000446e4 
4024a678 6880b508 69996803 bd084788 6880b508 
4024a688 69d96803 43014788 2000bf14 bd082001 
4024a698 43f7e92d 46164680 2900460f 2a00d131 
4024a6a8 6880d03f 23002200 0901f04f f8cd6801 
4024a6b8 68cd9000 460447a8 f1b5460d bf083fff 
4024a6c8 3ffff1b4 4818d104 f7b94478 e016e810 
4024a6d8 0008f8d8 6802463b 9000f8cd 463268d1 
4024a6e8 f1b14788 bf083fff 3ffff1b0 ebc4bf18 
4024a6f8 d1120400 4631480d f7b84478 4638eff8 
4024a708 6880e010 689c6803 1e0447a0 4808dc07 
4024a718 46224631 f7b84478 ea24efea 462074e4 
4024a728 4610e000 83fee8bd 0002e10d 0002e102 
4024a738 0002e104 2200b513 24006880 94006803 
4024a748 230068d9 f1b14788 bf083fff 3ffff1b0 

code around lr:
405945dc 4604460d f50d6809 68332080 6b0f3014 
405945ec 46286003 463747b8 682eb350 6b734628 
405945fc 46064798 e021b900 42866860 6821d101 
4059460c 6820e00c fe40f018 46302100 fe40f018 
4059461c 60204601 6060b908 6066e00a 682ab141 
4059462c 68d34628 47984632 460542b0 e034d106 
4059463c 49244823 44794478 fc40f014 e02c2500 
4059464c f7d54668 682afc23 4628a905 f44f68d3 
4059465c 47982280 4602a905 f7d54668 6828fccf 
4059466c 46286901 28004788 9d03d0ed 42956862 
4059467c 6821d101 6820e00b fe06f018 4628b125 
4059468c fe10f018 e0004601 e8844629 46680022 
4059469c fc38f7d5 f7d54668 f50dfcff 46282180 
405946ac 680a3114 429a683b f797d001 b007e8d0 
405946bc 2d80f50d bf00bdf0 0012f4e4 fffff320 
405946cc 00107707 00118096 7a00edd1 0ae7eef7
```

Comment: for which device you are getting this ?

Comment: Galaxy Grand2 (ms013g).. and Galaxy Tab3 7.0 (lt02wifi)

Comment: see my previous comment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329874/crosswalk-crashes-visual-studio-android-emulator/35388305#35388305